# zxing windows phone 8 Memory issue

Tags: memory, windows-phone, zxing

I am developing a barcode scanner.
My application scans a Barcode, than navigates to a second page (with barcodetext on it) and theres a button where i can scan a new barcode when its clicked. So now my problem is that the viewfinderbrush fills the Ram of the windows phone everytime I scan a barcode. If I scan 100 Barcodes, my applikation chrashes because of an out of memory. What can I do to free the memory?

In the zxing demo its the same issue, when I open the scanner and use the back key and open the scanner several times again, the ram is getting higher and higher.

My code for getting the ram:

```
string storage1 = (DeviceStatus.ApplicationCurrentMemoryUsage / 1000000).ToString() + "MB";
        lblram.Text = storage1 ;
```

I tried everything:
1. Navigationservice.removebackstack
2. Gc.collect (Garbagecollector)
3. disposing the camera
4. use of navigationservice.goback()

Nothing helps

I found out, that the problem is the viewfinderbrush, but i have to inizialize it every time, so thats a problem.

Code:

```
 protected override void OnNavigatedTo(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        string bla1 = (DeviceStatus.ApplicationCurrentMemoryUsage / 1000000).ToString() + "MB";
        lblram.Text = bla1;//("Ram: " + Math.Round(((bla1 / 1024)/ 1024), 2));

        _matches = new ObservableCollection<string>();
        matchesList.ItemsSource = _matches;

        // Check to see if the camera is available on the phone.
        if (PhotoCamera.IsCameraTypeSupported(CameraType.Primary) == true)
        {
            _photoCamera = new PhotoCamera(CameraType.Primary);

            // Event is fired when the PhotoCamera object has been initialized.
            _photoCamera.Initialized += PhotoCameraOnInitialized;
            _photoCamera.AutoFocusCompleted += PhotoCameraOnAutoFocusCompleted;
            NavigationService.RemoveBackEntry();
            viewfinderBrush.SetSource(_photoCamera);
        }
        else
        {
            // The camera is not supported on the phone.
            MessageBox.Show("A Camera is not available on this phone.");
        }
    }
```

What can I do to solve this problem?

Comment: Any solution founded ?